# Removing a line down the middle of a triangle without messing up the rest of the code

Tags: svg

Every time I try something it messes the whole code up. Is there anyone on here who can help me with this please. It's only a line, it shouldn't be that difficult, I don't understand why it is.

https://jsfiddle.net/r1kc162b/

```
<svg width="300" height="300" style="background-color:red;" viewBox="13 9.0 11 18">
    <path fill="currentColor" style="stroke: #0059dd; stroke-width:1px;color:black;" d="M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22 25,18 25,18 18.5,14 z"></path>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
<svg width="300" height="300" style="background-color:red;" viewBox="13 9.0 11 18">
<path fill="currentColor"
      style="stroke: #0059dd; stroke-width:1px;color:black;"
      d="M 12,26 12,10 25,18 z">
</path>
</svg>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1kc162b/2/)

Comment: Can you see if you can help me do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631081/placing-an-image-behind-a-border-and-2-verticle-lines