# Placing an image behind a border and 2 vertical lines

Tags: html, svg

What I want to do is to place an image behind a border and 2 vertical lines. I was thinking the vertical lines could be SVG, but I'm not sure how to set this up.

https://jsfiddle.net/q5xnxqkk/

```
<svg style="background-image: linear-gradient( to right,#000000 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, #000000 86px, #000000 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, #000000 177px );border: 3px solid #0059dd;padding: 62px 100px 62px 100px;  cursor: pointer;background-color:black;"
  width="60" height="72" viewBox="0 0 60 72">
    <path d="M30.001,12C16.767,12,6,22.765,6,35.999s10.766,23.999,24,23.999s24-10.765,24-23.999S43.235,12,30.001,12L30.001,12z" fill="#000000"></path>
    <path d="M39.201,34.34l-12-9c-0.607-0.455-1.419-0.528-2.095-0.189c-0.677,0.339-1.106,1.031-1.106,1.789v18c0,0.758,0.428,1.45,1.106,1.789c0.283,0.142,0.589,0.211,0.894,0.211c0.425,0,0.847-0.136,1.2-0.4l12-9c0.503-0.377,0.8-0.97,0.8-1.6C40.001,35.31,39.705,34.717,39.201,34.34z"
    fill="#E6DC00"></path>
    <path fill="#E6DC00 " d="M30,15c11.598,0,21,9.402,21,20.999s-9.401,20.999-21,20.999c-11.599,0-21-9.402-21-20.999S18.401,15,30,15 M30,9C15.112,9,3,21.111,3,35.999s12.112,26.999,27,26.999c14.888,0,27-12.111,27-26.999S44.888,9,30,9L30,9z" /></path>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue lines inside the box are not SVG paths, those are part of the linear-gradient, since you have it there I assume you know about how background image works.

There can be two approaches, one is to scrap the `linear-gradient` part from your SVG's `background-image` and instead use the `url('URL-TO-IMAGE')`, and for the lines use SVG's `<path>`. I am not an expert in SVG so can't tell you how to do that.

The second approach which I would recommend is to use [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds), yes, CSS allows layers of background images / gradients / colors and it is pretty simple.

`background-image: url("image-1.png"), url("image-2.png");`

or

`background-image: linear-gradient(....), url("image-2.png");`

Currently your SVG's `background-image` property is

```
background-image: linear-gradient( to right,#000000 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, #000000 86px, #000000 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, #000000 177px );
```

To have another image / linear gradient behind the current one you just separate the parts using a comma, like this

```
background-image: linear-gradient( to right,#000000 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, #000000 86px, #000000 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, #000000 177px ), url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x200');
```

But even if you do this you won't see the image at http://via.placeholder.com/200x200 in the box, that is due to the fact that there are fully opaque colors in your linear-gradient, well, let's change all the `#000000` in your linear-gradient's value to `transparent`

```
background-image: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px ), url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x200');
```

Here's a working demo:

```html
<svg style="background-image: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px,transparent  174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px ), url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x200');border: 3px solid #0059dd;padding: 62px 100px 62px 100px;  cursor: pointer;background-color:black; background-position: center;"
  width="60" height="72" viewBox="0 0 60 72">
    <path d="M30.001,12C16.767,12,6,22.765,6,35.999s10.766,23.999,24,23.999s24-10.765,24-23.999S43.235,12,30.001,12L30.001,12z" fill="#000000"></path>
    <path d="M39.201,34.34l-12-9c-0.607-0.455-1.419-0.528-2.095-0.189c-0.677,0.339-1.106,1.031-1.106,1.789v18c0,0.758,0.428,1.45,1.106,1.789c0.283,0.142,0.589,0.211,0.894,0.211c0.425,0,0.847-0.136,1.2-0.4l12-9c0.503-0.377,0.8-0.97,0.8-1.6C40.001,35.31,39.705,34.717,39.201,34.34z"
    fill="#E6DC00"></path>
    <path fill="#E6DC00 " d="M30,15c11.598,0,21,9.402,21,20.999s-9.401,20.999-21,20.999c-11.599,0-21-9.402-21-20.999S18.401,15,30,15 M30,9C15.112,9,3,21.111,3,35.999s12.112,26.999,27,26.999c14.888,0,27-12.111,27-26.999S44.888,9,30,9L30,9z" /></path>
  </svg>
```

Please study the code and experiment with it, that's the best way to learn more!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
svg {
  border:3px solid #0059dd;
  padding:62px 100px 62px 100px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:black
}
```

```html
  <svg width="60" height="72">
     <path fill="#E6DC00"d="M39.201,34.34l-12-9 c-0.607-0.455-1.419-0.528-2.095-0.189 c-0.677,0.339-1.106,1.031-1.106,1.789 v18 c0,0.758,0.428,1.45,1.106,1.789 c0.283,0.142,0.589,0.211,0.894,0.211 c0.425,0,0.847-0.136,1.2-0.4 l12-9 c0.503-0.377,0.8-0.97,0.8-1.6 C40.001,35.31,39.705,34.717,39.201,34.34 z"/>
     <path fill="#E6DC00 "d="M30,15 c11.598,0,21,9.402,21,20.999 s-9.401,20.999-21,20.999 c-11.599,0-21-9.402-21-20.999 S18.401,15,30,15  M30,9 C15.112,9,3,21.111,3,35.999 s12.112,26.999,27,26.999 c14.888,0,27-12.111,27-26.999 S44.888,9,30,9 L30,9 z"/>
     <path stroke="#0059dd" stroke-width="3" d="M 10,-62 v 196 M 50,-62 v 196"/>
  </svg>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5xnxqkk/1/)

Comment: No, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/u7c3tqah/ I would like the image to go 'behind' the lines. http://via.placeholder.com/200x200 Is this possible to do?

Comment: like this then? svg is rendered in the order it is written, so place the image and then the lines

Comment: Can you copy the one on the bottom to look like the one on the top? https://jsfiddle.net/8gj322p7/1/ Moving the lines so they are set up the same.

Comment: I'm confused on how I would align the lines up so they match with the above code. Can you show me please? https://jsfiddle.net/8gj322p7/1/

Comment: i don 't get you - where do you want the lines? what's wrong with using the gradient method? the svg path that does the lines uses M 3,-62, which moves absolutely to (3,-62) (to the image size and padding), then moves relatively vertically (lowercase v) to (3,-62+196) = (3,134). Change the 3 to whatever x co-ord you want.

Comment: If I can't place the lines anywhere I want within the box what use is it?

Comment: but you can place the lines where you want!

Comment: they wouldn't go over the image like that, and anyway, you can :     <path stroke="#0059dd" stroke-width="3" d="M -17,-62 v 196 M 77,-62 v 196"/>

Comment: I just did that and no lines are showing: https://jsfiddle.net/8gj322p7/3/

Comment: that's exactly the same fiddle as the last one

Comment: I added in:  <path stroke="#0059dd" stroke-width="3" d="M -17,-62 v 196 M 77,-62 v 196"/>

Comment: but you did that in 8gj322p7/3. is there a real problem here?

Comment: There are no vertical lines showing, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i see this, which has 2 vertical lines

[image]

And a snippet:

```css
svg {
  border:3px solid #0059dd;
  padding:62px 100px 62px 100px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:#aaaaaa
}
```

```html
<svg width="60" height="72">
   <path fill="#000000" d="M30.001,12 C16.767,12,6,22.765,6,35.999 s10.766,23.999,24,23.999 s24-10.765,24-23.999 S43.235,12,30.001,12 L30.001,12 z"/>
   <path fill="#E6DC00"d="M39.201,34.34l-12-9 c-0.607-0.455-1.419-0.528-2.095-0.189 c-0.677,0.339-1.106,1.031-1.106,1.789 v18 c0,0.758,0.428,1.45,1.106,1.789 c0.283,0.142,0.589,0.211,0.894,0.211 c0.425,0,0.847-0.136,1.2-0.4 l12-9 c0.503-0.377,0.8-0.97,0.8-1.6 C40.001,35.31,39.705,34.717,39.201,34.34 z"/>
   <path fill="#E6DC00 "d="M30,15 c11.598,0,21,9.402,21,20.999 s-9.401,20.999-21,20.999 c-11.599,0-21-9.402-21-20.999 S18.401,15,30,15  M30,9 C15.112,9,3,21.111,3,35.999 s12.112,26.999,27,26.999 c14.888,0,27-12.111,27-26.999 S44.888,9,30,9 L30,9 z"/>
   <path stroke="#0059dd" stroke-width="3" d="M -17,-62 v 196 M 77,-62 v 196"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: No lines are showing here, how come? https://i.imgur.com/1iIjE54.png Why are we seeing 2 different things? I don't get it.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet on here? Something must be different.

Comment: can you too? perhaps it's a setting at JSFiddle

Comment: How do you do that? How do you post a code snippet on here?

Comment: do what? add a snippet? copy code from JSF, click 'new answer' at SO, right of image in buttons at top of editing panel is 'code snippet'. paste code into this, test and save

Comment: i get that here http://www.freecodeformat.com/svg-editor.php and here http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.htm but not SO or JSF

Comment: Meaning, it only works some of the time, depending on where you put it?

Comment: No vertical lines are shown on here: (http://htmledit.squarefree.com/) Image: https://i.imgur.com/l8L8ywa.png What could be the issue, and is there a solution for it?

Comment: i'd opt for various svg render engine capabilities

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: are you adding the CSS, otherwise the lines are rendered off-element