# Would it be possible to use linear-gradient with transparency, where behind it would be an Image?

Tags: html, svg

Would it be possible to use linear-gradient with transparency, where behind it would be an Image?

Is this something I would be able to do?

https://jsfiddle.net/w73d3o36/

```
<svg style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/266x150');border: 3px solid #0059dd; background-repeat: no-repeat;padding: 36px 100px 36px 100px ;  cursor: pointer;background: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px );" width="60" height="72" viewBox="0 0 60 72">

 <path d="M30.001,12C16.767,12,6,22.765,6,35.999s10.766,23.999,24,23.999s24-10.765,24-23.999S43.235,12,30.001,12L30.001,12z" fill="#000000"></path>
  <path d="M39.201,34.34l-12-9c-0.607-0.455-1.419-0.528-2.095-0.189c-0.677,0.339-1.106,1.031-1.106,1.789v18c0,0.758,0.428,1.45,1.106,1.789c0.283,0.142,0.589,0.211,0.894,0.211c0.425,0,0.847-0.136,1.2-0.4l12-9c0.503-0.377,0.8-0.97,0.8-1.6C40.001,35.31,39.705,34.717,39.201,34.34z"
  fill="#E6DC00"></path>
  <path fill="#E6DC00 " d="M30,15c11.598,0,21,9.402,21,20.999s-9.401,20.999-21,20.999c-11.599,0-21-9.402-21-20.999S18.401,15,30,15 M30,9C15.112,9,3,21.111,3,35.999s12.112,26.999,27,26.999c14.888,0,27-12.111,27-26.999S44.888,9,30,9L30,9z" /></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: In what way do the answers to your [previous almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631081/placing-an-image-behind-a-border-and-2-vertical-lines) fail to address your needs?

Comment: I might if I could understand what you wanted.

Comment: I wanted to replicate the spacing of the vertical SVG lines as they are shown in the top image. How do I do that? https://jsfiddle.net/8gj322p7/5/

Comment: Are you going to help me with the code, do you understand now what I'm trying to do after I explained it?

Comment: I don't need to help you, you've answered your question below haven't you. If that is an answer, explain why it answers your question and we're done here, if it's not an answer to the question, delete it.

Answer (score 1):

An element is allowed to have multiple backgrounds. Just separate them with a comma. The one listed last will be at the back.

```css
svg {
  padding: 39px 103px 39px 103px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  background: linear-gradient( to right,
                               transparent 83px,
                               #0059dd 83px,
                               #0059dd 86px,
                               transparent 86px,
                               transparent 174px,
                               #0059dd 174px,
                               #0059dd 177px,
                               transparent 177px ),
              url('http://via.placeholder.com/266x150');
}
```

```html
<svg width="60" height="72" viewBox="0 0 60 72">

 <path d="M30.001,12C16.767,12,6,22.765,6,35.999s10.766,23.999,24,23.999s24-10.765,24-23.999S43.235,12,30.001,12L30.001,12z" fill="#000000"></path>
  <path d="M39.201,34.34l-12-9c-0.607-0.455-1.419-0.528-2.095-0.189c-0.677,0.339-1.106,1.031-1.106,1.789v18c0,0.758,0.428,1.45,1.106,1.789c0.283,0.142,0.589,0.211,0.894,0.211c0.425,0,0.847-0.136,1.2-0.4l12-9c0.503-0.377,0.8-0.97,0.8-1.6C40.001,35.31,39.705,34.717,39.201,34.34z"
  fill="#E6DC00"></path>
  <path fill="#E6DC00 " d="M30,15c11.598,0,21,9.402,21,20.999s-9.401,20.999-21,20.999c-11.599,0-21-9.402-21-20.999S18.401,15,30,15 M30,9C15.112,9,3,21.111,3,35.999s12.112,26.999,27,26.999c14.888,0,27-12.111,27-26.999S44.888,9,30,9L30,9z" />

</svg>
```

Answer (score -2):

**The Answer:**
 https://jsfiddle.net/6v0b7ppj/1/

```
   <svg style="border: 3px solid #0059dd; background-repeat: no-repeat;padding: 36px 100px 36px 100px ;  cursor: pointer;background: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#0059DD 83px, #0059DD 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #0059DD 174px, #0059DD 177px, transparent 177px ), url('http://via.placeholder.com/266x150');" width="60" height="72" viewBox="0 0 60 72">

 <path d="M30.001,12C16.767,12,6,22.765,6,35.999s10.766,23.999,24,23.999s24-10.765,24-23.999S43.235,12,30.001,12L30.001,12z" fill="#000000"></path>
  <path d="M39.201,34.34l-12-9c-0.607-0.455-1.419-0.528-2.095-0.189c-0.677,0.339-1.106,1.031-1.106,1.789v18c0,0.758,0.428,1.45,1.106,1.789c0.283,0.142,0.589,0.211,0.894,0.211c0.425,0,0.847-0.136,1.2-0.4l12-9c0.503-0.377,0.8-0.97,0.8-1.6C40.001,35.31,39.705,34.717,39.201,34.34z"
  fill="#E6DC00"></path>
  <path fill="#E6DC00 " d="M30,15c11.598,0,21,9.402,21,20.999s-9.401,20.999-21,20.999c-11.599,0-21-9.402-21-20.999S18.401,15,30,15 M30,9C15.112,9,3,21.111,3,35.999s12.112,26.999,27,26.999c14.888,0,27-12.111,27-26.999S44.888,9,30,9L30,9z" /></path>

</svg>
```

Comment: Then you should explain why (in the answer), at the moment it's a code dump which is not really useful to anyone else.